# How do I push untracked branch A to origin/feature/A

Tags: git, git-push

I have an untracked branch that was originally cloned from a remote branch called `origin/develop`. I want to push this branch to the remote branch `origin/feature/A`. `origin/feature/A` does not exist yet. I want it to be created when I push. We already have branches `origin/feature/XYZ` on the remote and I'm trying to stay consistent. The branch locally is called `A`.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to `git push origin A:feature/A`.

From [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> `<refspec>…`
>
> Specify what destination ref to update with what source object. The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus +, followed by the source object `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`.
>
> …
>
> The `<dst>` tells which ref on the remote side is updated with this push.

As knittl points out in the comments, you can add the `-u` flag to make your local `A` branch track the new `origin/feature/A` branch.

Comment: And maybe use `-u` to automatically setup the branch to track the remote branch